# Where does Google Music store the "offline tracks"?

Tags: android, offline-caching

I have about 8 gigs of music stored within Google Music, and I recently got sick of streaming (and risking data charges), so I painstakingly allowed it to be stored offline. So my fresh 16 gig SD card now only had 8 gigs left. Then, I flashed a new rom, thinking that all my music would still be there cached (or however it works), but I was wrong. When I click "show offline tracks only" within the Google Music app, it shows nothing, yet my SD card still only has 8 gigs of space left.

So, my question is, where are these offline tracks stored on my SD card so I can go in and delete them, to free up space so I can back them all up again?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com is the place for this

Comment: Okay, sorry I'll move it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache/music`

Comment: seems to be at `/sdcard/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files/music` now, at least on my droid.

Comment: same for me: files/music instead of cache/music, but thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: Or `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music/`. But you need a rooted phone to access them there.

Comment: is there any other location? The latest one, is no where to be found in any of those locations.

Comment: No files in that location anymore...

Comment: This seems to be outdated.

Comment: I've found the files at /data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music. Although they are labeled as .mp3's, they are not playable as such; probably to prevent copying them off to play.